# Adding onclick event to a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have the following link in html:

```
<a class="link_class" href="somelink.com">Link</a>
```

Without editing the HTML, I want to add an onclick event so it'll look like this:

```
<a class="link_class" onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('somelink.com');" href="somelink.com">Link</a>
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: Why not just unobtrusively add the event handler and then call `gtag_report_conversion()` from that?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add with `attr`

```
$('.link_class').attr("onclick", "return gtag_report_conversion('somelink.com');")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/gu14dryt/4/

Comment: Is there a way to add this so it's reflected in the html code? so if I open source-code I actually see it as part of the code, as in my original post?

Answer (score 3):

To select *all* anchor elements or "link_class" elements and add a you can use:

```
    $("a.link_class").on("click", function(){
        //your code here
    });
```

(to select all links use "a". To select only `.link_class` elements use "link_class". The above code will select only links with class `link_class`)

You want this to run when the document is *ready*, so you wrap it on:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.link_class").on("click", function(){
            //your code here
        });
    });
```

(this probably already exists within your application, just make sure you put the code that selects the links inside the document.ready callback)

Again, this will attach the event to **all** items that match the selector. If you only want a specific item, give it an **id**, and use that to select it.

```
    $("#a-specific-id").on("click", function(){
        //your code here
    });
```

Alternatively, if you can't give it an ID, and only want to target a specific item, you could try the `eq` method like:

```
    $("a.link_class").eq(INDEX).on("click", function(){
        //your code here
    });
```

Where INDEX is the index of the specific link in the collection of links returned by the selector.

I think you will benefit from spending some time at the jQuery learning center:
https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Combining the previously posted answers, and in case someone wants to track a specific conversion, and target ALL the links that contain herf="tel:", you can try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("a[href^='tel']").attr("onclick", "return gtag_report_conversion('tel:12345678');")
});
```

Also If you are using a CMS like WordPress, and you can add jQuery, you have to replace $ with jQuery. So the code will be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("a[href^='tel']").attr("onclick", "return gtag_report_conversion('tel:12345678');")
});
```